# how to disable custom dates along with previous dates in datepicker?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery

I am trying to disable some dates along with that  I, am trying to disable **past dates** as well.Kindly, give some help where I can delete past dates in date picker.

```
            <div class='input-group date' id='datepicker1'>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtdatepicker"> 
            </asp:TextBox>
            </div>
        
             <script type="text/javascript">
          
          $(function () {
            var disableSpecificDates =  ["19-8-2021", "28-8-2021", "26- 
            8-2021"];
           
            $('#datepicker1').datepicker({
                format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
                beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                    dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + 
           "-" + 
                date.getFullYear();
                    if (disableSpecificDates.indexOf(dmy) != -1) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    else {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            });
            $('#datepicker1').datepicker("setDate", new Date());
            });
           
          </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting you can disable the past date.

```js
$('#datepicker1').datepicker("minDate", new Date());
});
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.